# asp.net core 1.1 identity project upgrade to 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

recently upgraded an asp.net core 1.1 project to 3.0 project. All packages are updated. and the startup.cs fixes are all done based on documentations I found online.

I am having series of errors as with users, roles and claims areas in the existing code which was working before. I need to find a solution with minimal DB change. Im pretty sure im missing something simple.

Here is an example code where roles do not have the claims.
which gives error CS1061
'Role' does not contain a definition for 'Claims' and no accessible extension method 'Claims' accepting a first argument of type 'Role' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
var roles = await _db.Roles.Where(x => x.Claims.Any(y => y.ClaimType == "Leadership")).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

CS1061  'User' does not contain a definition for 'Roles' and no accessible extension method 'Roles' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
await _db.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).....
```

I have custom definition of user and role with added variables.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
```

Here is the model creation

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
 ........
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.HasDefaultSchema("core");
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users", "core");
        builder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles", "core");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("UserClaims", "core");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("UserRoles", "core").HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>().ToTable("UserExternalLogins", "core").HasKey(x => x.ProviderKey);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>().ToTable("UserTokens", "core").HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.Value });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>().ToTable("RoleClaims", "core");
```

and also startup.cs portion of ConfigureServices

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.            
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
            sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 10,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
            }), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/unauthorized";
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizeMemberHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizeMemberOrBotHandler>();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Mgmt", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Mgmt"));
            options.AddPolicy("Member", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MemberRequirement()));
            options.AddPolicy("MemberOrBot", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MemberOrBotRequirement()));
        });

        services.AddScoped<ShoppingBag>();
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueCountLimit = 2048);

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddRouting(options => {
            options.LowercaseUrls = true;
            options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        });
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

Please let me know if I forgotten any information, thank you.

Comment: The `User`/`Role` entities don't have these properties. I don't think they did even back in 1.1.

Comment: Those properties were removed in 2.0. Have a read of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.0).